# Search without tags if nothing was found?

Tags: feature-request, search

I was using the Stack Overflow search like this:

`[WARNING] The version of the bundled JRE is too low.`

Which is warning I got during development, which I just copied into the search box. Strangely enough I got 0 results.
I knew there was an answer ([Fixing Install4j warnings related to external references to JRE bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922038/fixing-install4j-warnings-related-to-external-references-to-jre-bundles)) that has this text. After a few moments, I realized that SO interpreted the `[WARNING]` part as a tag I wanted to filter on.

It might be convenient to have a link "retry search without smart query" (This is how Atlassian JIRA does it) when there are 0 results.

Comment: Or you could just escape the brackets: `\[WARNING\] The version of the bundled JRE is too low.`

Comment: @ArtjomB. That's true but not everyone will know the search syntax.